# Iterating through an object leaves undefined

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

I have an object `rawUser` in `rawUser` I have two arrays `insertConfigurations & packagingInstructions`

I'm currently mapping through these two arrays.

This is working as expected. Here is my code snippet:

```js
const rawUser = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Barnes",
  config: {
    insertConfigurations: [{
        id: "B22",
        type: "Insert",
        title: "Barnes",
        subtitle: "Welcome Book",
        dropInConditional: "FIRST"
    }],
    packagingInstructions: [{
      id: "B22",
      type: "sticker",
      title: "Barnes",
      packagingType: "STICKER"
    }]
  }
};

console.log(dataReturn());

function dataReturn() {
  return {
    id: rawUser.id,
    name: rawUser.name,
    insertConfigurations: rawUser.config.insertConfigurations
      ? rawUser.config.insertConfigurations.map(
          (rawConfig) => {
            return {
              id: rawConfig.id,
              title: rawConfig.title,
              subtitle: rawConfig.subtitle,
              type: rawConfig.type,
              dropInConditional: rawConfig.dropInConditional
            };
          }
        )
      : undefined,
    packagingInstructions: rawUser.config.packagingInstructions
      ? rawUser.config.packagingInstructions.map(
          (rawConfig) => {
            return {
              id: rawConfig.id,
              title: rawConfig.title,
              type: rawConfig.type,
              packagingType: rawConfig.packagingType
            };
          }
        )
      : undefined
  };
}
```

I am now trying to accomplish the same thing but now `insertConfigurations & packagingInstructions` are objects and not an array. For example:

```
const rawTenant = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Barnes",
  config: {
    dropInConfigurations: {
        id: "TF50",
        type: "Insert",
        title: "Barnes",
        subtitle: "Welcome Booklet",
        dropInConditional: "FIRST"

    },
    packagingInstructions: {
      id: "TF50",
      type: "sticker",
      title: "Barnes",
      packagingType: "STICKER"
    }
  }
};
```

Because they are objects I can no longer `map` them as the first example. So I tried working around this but using `Object.entries` and then `map`. But I am not getting an array of undefined objects multiple times.

Here is my code snippet `Object.entries` :

```js
const rawUser = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Barnes",
  config: {
    insertConfigurations: {
        id: "B22",
        type: "Insert",
        title: "Barnes",
        subtitle: "Welcome Book",
        dropInConditional: "FIRST"
    },
    packagingInstructions:{
      id: "B22",
      type: "sticker",
      title: "Barnes",
      packagingType: "STICKER"
    }
  }
};

console.log(dataReturn());

function dataReturn() {
  return {
    id: rawUser.id,
    name: rawUser.name,
    insertConfigurations: rawUser.config.insertConfigurations
      ? Object.entries(rawUser.config.insertConfigurations).map(
        ([key, rawConfig]) => {
            return {
              id: rawConfig.id,
              title: rawConfig.title,
              subtitle: rawConfig.subtitle,
              type: rawConfig.type,
              dropInConditional: rawConfig.dropInConditional
            };
          }
        )
      : undefined,
    packagingInstructions: rawUser.config.packagingInstructions
      ? Object.entries(rawUser.config.packagingInstructions).map(
        ([key, rawConfig]) => {
            return {
              id: rawConfig.id,
              title: rawConfig.title,
              type: rawConfig.type,
              packagingType: rawConfig.packagingType
            };
          }
        )
      : undefined
  };
}
```

How can I achieve the outcome of the first snippet when `insertConfigurations & packagingInstructions` are both now objects. My expected outcome is identical to the first snippet.

I expect

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Barnes",
  "insertConfigurations": [
    {
      "id": "B22",
      "title": "Barnes",
      "subtitle": "Welcome Book",
      "type": "Insert",
      "dropInConditional": "FIRST"
    }
  ],
  "packagingInstructions": [
    {
      "id": "B22",
      "title": "Barnes",
      "type": "sticker",
      "packagingType": "STICKER"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @neoslo, was my answer helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by introducing a function like `convertValueWith`, that can take the `value` and a `conversion` function and return either an array or object depending on the type of `value`.

```js
function convertValueWith(val, conversion) {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
        return val.map(conversion)
    } else if (val && typeof val === 'object') {
        return [conversion(val)]
    }
}
```

Then you can write some conversion functions:

```js
const insertConfigurations = (val) =>
    convertValueWith(val, (rawConfig) => {
        return {
            id: rawConfig.id,
            title: rawConfig.title,
            subtitle: rawConfig.subtitle,
            type: rawConfig.type,
            dropInConditional: rawConfig.dropInConditional
        };
    });

const packagingInstructions = (val) => 
    convertValueWith(val, (rawConfig) => {
        return {
            id: rawConfig.id,
            title: rawConfig.title,
            type: rawConfig.type,
            packagingType: rawConfig.packagingType
        };
    });
```

Your resulting `dataReturn` function becomes a bit cleaner:

```js
function dataReturn(rawThing) {
    return {
        id: rawThing.id,
        name: rawThing.name,
        insertConfigurations: insertConfigurations(rawThing.config.insertConfigurations),
        packagingInstructions: packagingInstructions(rawThing.config.packagingInstructions),
    };
}
```

```js
const rawUser = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Barnes",
  config: {
    insertConfigurations: [{
      id: "B22",
      type: "Insert",
      title: "Barnes",
      subtitle: "Welcome Book",
      dropInConditional: "FIRST"
    }],
    packagingInstructions: [{
      id: "B22",
      type: "sticker",
      title: "Barnes",
      packagingType: "STICKER"
    }]
  }
};

const rawTenant = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Barnes",
  config: {
    insertConfigurations: {
      id: "TF50",
      type: "Insert",
      title: "Barnes",
      subtitle: "Welcome Booklet",
      dropInConditional: "FIRST"
    },
    packagingInstructions: {
      id: "TF50",
      type: "sticker",
      title: "Barnes",
      packagingType: "STICKER"
    }
  }
};


function convertValueWith(val, conversion) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    return val.map(conversion)
  } else if (val && typeof val === 'object') {
    return [conversion(val)]
  }
}

const insertConfigurations = (val) =>
  convertValueWith(val, (rawConfig) => {
    return {
      id: rawConfig.id,
      title: rawConfig.title,
      subtitle: rawConfig.subtitle,
      type: rawConfig.type,
      dropInConditional: rawConfig.dropInConditional
    };
  });

const packagingInstructions = (val) =>
  convertValueWith(val, (rawConfig) => {
    return {
      id: rawConfig.id,
      title: rawConfig.title,
      type: rawConfig.type,
      packagingType: rawConfig.packagingType
    };
  });

function dataReturn(rawThing) {
  return {
    id: rawThing.id,
    name: rawThing.name,
    insertConfigurations: insertConfigurations(rawThing.config.insertConfigurations),
    packagingInstructions: packagingInstructions(rawThing.config.packagingInstructions),
  };
}

console.log(dataReturn(rawUser));
console.log(dataReturn(rawTenant));
```

Comment: Just one remark from my end. Don't know if it is a possible input but if any of `insertConfigurations` and `packagingInstructions` were to be `null` your script will crash. This is because `typeof null === "object"` yields `true`. So you should either check for this in `convertValueWith()` or account for that in all of your `conversion` functions.

Comment: @Mushroomator Good catch! Fixed.